# Pass Java static method to Clojure function args

Tags: clojure

Syntax error when passing *Java* static method to *Clojure* function args directly:

```
(filter Character/isUpperCase "aBcD")
```

Why does it want the wrapper then work?

```
(filter #(Character/isUpperCase %) "aBcD")
```

Answer (score 1):

Because filter takes a Clojure function as first argument, and one or more collections as rest.

A Java method is not a Clojure function. Wrapping the method in an anonymous function makes it one.